# plotly : Difficulty in displaying a string with two dollar signs in plot annotation

Tags: python, string, annotations, plotly, dollar-sign

I have a string with two dollar sign, and I want to be used as a text annotation below my plot.
This code created a string, and you can see its output.

> str=f"Maximum: {a} , ${numerize.numerize(b)}\t"+f"Minimum: {c} , ${numerize.numerize(d)}"

> Output: Maximum: 1396 , $544.41M  Minimum: 1399 , $255.31M

but when I use str in below, plotly changes the font and shows unexpected characters:

```
annotations = []
annotations.append(dict(xref='paper', yref='paper', x=0.5, y=-0.15,
                              xanchor='center', yanchor='top',
                              text=str,
                              font=dict(family="Courier New",
                                        size=14,
                                        color='rgb(100,100,100)'),
                              showarrow=False))
fig.update_layout(annotations=annotations)
```

and the result in the plot:
[unexpected annotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIKdv.png)

How can I fix this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Plotly: How to use both dollar signs and linebreaks in annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63763576/plotly-how-to-use-both-dollar-signs-and-linebreaks-in-annotations) need to use HTML printable characters in text that becomes HTML
- hence solution becomes

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from numerize import numerize

fig = go.Figure()

# # Output: Maximum: 1396 , $544.41M Minimum: 1399 , $255.31M
a = 1396
b = 544.41 * 10 ** 6
c = 1399
d = 255.31 * 10 ** 6
str = (
    f"Maximum: {a} , &#36;{numerize.numerize(b)}\t"
    + f"Minimum: {c} , &#36;{numerize.numerize(d)}"
)
ano
annotations = []
annotations.append(
    dict(
        xref="paper",
        yref="paper",
        x=0.5,
        y=-0.15,
        xanchor="center",
        yanchor="top",
        text=str,
        font=dict(family="Courier New", size=14, color="rgb(100,100,100)"),
        showarrow=False,
    )
)
fig.update_layout(annotations=annotations)
```